# move cloudwatch stream logs to Redshift in real time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am new to AWS, I want to move my aws real time cloudwatch stream logs to Redshift Table.I am thinking like first I want to move my cloudwatch stream logs to lambda funtion from there to Redshift. If you have any idea how to get those cloudwatch logs to lambda function, Please let me know. I dont any idea on it. I went through lot of docs but I didnot find proper lambda function to get stream logs from cloudwatch.

Comment: Have a look at using s3 for storing the logs and then access with athena or redshift spectrum

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for reply. yes I am trying to do that using create export task API but facing issue while giving giving from time to to time. Because my logs are real time logs let me know if you have any idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should add subscription to your CloudWatch logs to a Kinesis/ Firehose.
 Check -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html

Comment: And Firehose can automatically load the data to Redshift for you if desired.